# Given an input point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, select (one of) the closest point(s) from a fixed large set of points given in advance

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, discrete-geometry

We are given a set $S$ of $m\gg 1$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In the problem I am trying to solve, in a sequential fashion, we obtain a *new* point $p_r\not\in S$ at each round $r\ge 1$ and the goal is to find the point $s_r\in S$ closest to $p_r$ in $S$, possibly in an approximate way, according to the Euclidean distance.

---

**Question:** How can we preprocess and organize the information of the points in $S$, to solve this problem focusing on the trade-off between time complexity and distance minimization?

I guess we can use sampling techniques and randomized algorithms/data structures, to obtain a solution with theoretical performance guarantees in expectation (or with high probability) over the internal algorithmic randomization. Is there in the related literature any solution already found for this problem?

Comment: Is this the secretary problem?

Comment: I think this type of problem usually goes under the name (vector) quantization. There are some well established preprocessing approaches, e.g., k-d trees. Since nearest-neighbor models are standard examples in machine learning, you can find lots of useful explainers online (I found some by googling "nearest neighbor quantization k-d trees").

Comment: $p_r=s_r$?$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Thank you @YoavKallus

Comment: @JamesMartin, set $S$ is fixed and given at time $0$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka thank you for your question. No, we just have to find the closest point in $S$ at each round and the main computational issue is that $S$ is too large to check all points it contains.

Comment: Can $S$ be enclosed in a cube of finite size? If so, divide the cube into subcubes (you can also have a hierarchy of progressively smaller ones) and for each subcube, list the elements of $S$ that are contained. Then for any given $p_r $, you can immediately look up the subcube(s) in the vicinity and do a residual search just within those. If $S$ is pretty homogeneously distributed, one subdivision will do - if there are multiple scales, you'll need a hierarchy of subdivisions.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelEngelhardt Yes. However, if we recursively partition the hypercube into equally large sub-hypercubes, we obtain a hierarchical tree with a fanout exponential in $n$, and the computational complexity will be too large. Correct me please if I am wrong. Furthermore, let two sub-hypercubes of equal volume be called $d$-adjacent if the points in common lie on a $d$-dimensional surface. The number of sub-hypercubes that are $d$-adjacent to a given sub-hypercube of equal volume, is exactly equal to ${n\choose d}$, which suggests that even exploring the neighborhood is expensive too.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused. I don't think you can mean "find the point closest to $s_r$ in $S$". Probably you mean "find the point in $S$ which is closest to $p_r$"?

Comment: You are right @JamesMartin ! A small typo yielding a big misunderstanding. Thank you! Sorry, I did not even understand your first comment.

Comment: I am assuming that you're willing to invest an unlimited amount of time into the preprocessing - if there are additional constraints there, that can of course change things. But once you've got $S$ sorted into the hypercubes, it seems like a pretty quick lookup to me - unless $n$ is really large, as you note. I suspect the form of good algorithms depends on $n$ - if you don't say anything more about $n$, it's hard to say something specific.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I understand your viewpoint. Yes, it depends on $n$, which is not large as $m$ (otherwise I would have written $n\gg 1$), but it is not even constant (otherwise I would have written it is constant). I thought it was fine to think by "default" that $n$ is a "non-constant variable". Here, since the fanout is exponential in $n$, even if we had infinite amount time to build the hierarchical tree, how could we traverse it down? Is it possibile to make something like a binary search among the children of each sub-hypercube. If it is, then we have something interesting.

Comment: To my mind, the hierarchy is only necessary to the extent that you don't know the density of points. You just need to find the subdivision granularity at which there are only a few points of $S$ left to compare with. That shouldn't take too long - try an initial hypercube size, see how many points are in there, and from that predict the hypercube size at which there should be only a few points. Iterate. You should find the right granularity pretty quickly.

Comment: OK @MichaelEngelhardt I will think about it. I have the feeling that if we have an (adversarial arrangements of points) similar somewhat to the one I attempted to describe here https://mathoverflow.net/q/383900/115803, it is still unlikely this strategy can work, but maybe I am wrong. In any case, it would be interesting and useful to find a rigorous characterization of these adversarial point arrangements in $S$, to be able to identify a wide class of inputs where this operations can be done in a computational efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complex but well-studied topic.
Perhaps starting here (Chapter 43) will help you focus on your particular application:

> Andoni, Alexandr, and Piotr Indyk.
> "Nearest neighbors in high-dimensional spaces."
> [*Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry*](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Third-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781498711395).
> (2017). [PDF of preliminary version of Ch.43](http://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/chap43.pdf).

Here's a little snippet:

> Almost all algorithms for proximity problems in high-dimensional spaces proceed
> by reducing the problem to the problem of finding an approximate near neighbor,
> which is the decision version of the approximate nearest-neighbor problem. [...]
> All the NNS algorithms are based on space partitions (even if not always framed
> this way). We distinguish two broad classes of partitions: 1) data-independent
> approaches, where the partition is independent of the given dataset $P$, and 2)
> data-dependent approaches, where the partition depends on the dataset $P$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will read it carefully.